# Delayed state change in hook

Tags: javascript, reactjs

So I've recently started to change some functionalities into `hook's`, one of which is supposed to load some components from a `slides array`, get a position number from `currentSlide` and then create a tag name combining these two.

```
import React, { useReducer, useRef } from "react";

const initialState = {
    slides: ['Slide1','Slide2','Slide3'],
    currentSlide: 0,
    initialX: 0,
    endX: 0
}

const reducer = (state, action) => {
    switch (action.type) {
        case 'pull-slides':
            return { ...state, slides: action.value };
        case 'swipe-right':
            return { ...state, currentSlide: state.currentSlide + 1 }
        case 'swipe-left':
            return { ...state, currentSlide: state.currentSlide - 1 }
        case 'set-initialX':
            return {
                ...state, initialX: action.position
            }
        case 'set-endX':
            return {
                ...state, endX: action.position
            }
        default:
            throw new Error('Unexpected action');
    }
}

const swipeDetection = () => {
    const [state, dispatch] = useReducer(reducer, initialState)
    const swipeArea = useRef(null)

    function _onMouseDown(e) {
        console.log(e.screenX)
        dispatch({ type: 'set-initialX', position: e.screenX })
        console.log(state)
    }

    function _onMouseUp(e) {
        console.log(e.screenX)
        dispatch({ type: 'set-endX', position: e.screenX })
        console.log(state)

        if ((state.initialX < state.endX) && ((state.endX - state.initialX) > 350)) {
            console.log('right')
            if (state.currentSlide < (state.slides.length - 1)) {
                console.log('right')
                dispatch({ type: 'swipe-right' })
            }
        } else if ((state.initialX > state.endX) && ((state.initialX - state.endX) > 350)) {
            console.log('left')
            if (state.currentSlide > 0) {
                dispatch({ type: 'swipe-left' })
               console.log('left')
            }
        }
    }

    const TagName = state.slides[state.currentSlide]

    return (
        typeof TagName == 'function' ? (
            <div className="h-100" ref={swipeArea} onMouseDown={_onMouseDown} onMouseUp={_onMouseUp}>
                <TagName />
            </div>
        ) : ''
     )
}

export default swipeDetection
```

In order to switch from one component to another I decided to use `onMouseDown`/`onMouseUp` instead of `onMouseMove` events.

So when you click down it stores the `screenX` and when you release the mouse is stores the `screenX` again and compares the two values to see how far you've *swiped* left or right.

This seems to work pretty well from what I could tell, except for the fact that you have to *swipe* in one direction twice in order for it to actually *change* the `currentSlide` value.

I have no idea why this is happening, granted I am really new to `Hooks` and I'm just getting my *code-legs* (like see-legs but for programmers?).

I've tried different approaches and materials but I couldn't really find anything relevant to my case, any ideas for why something like this would happen?

I've added the `console.log` for `e.screenX` and `state` to check and see what is happening on click, so when you click it does immediately return the `e.screenX` value and the `state`, but the `state` is not updated with the value for some reason...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`dispatch` (just like `setState` and any other call to React to trigger an update) gets deferred, so it won't run immeadiately. Additionally dispatching causes a rerender, which will execute the whole component function again, which will create a new `state` variable inside of it. No matter what you do, `state` will always point to the old state. Therefore this:

```
   state.initialX < state.endX
```

will always operate on the previous state. To solve this do the following:

1) Remove `endX` and `endY` from the state. If the finger gets raised you want to check for a swipe immeadiately. There is no need for persisting that position.

2) There are just two events needed for your reducer: touchdown and touchup. Everything else should be done inside the reducer.

```
    const SlideSwiper = ({ slides }) => {
      const [{ currentSlide }, touch] = useReducer(({ currentSlide, start }, { type, position }) => {
         if(type === "up") {
           if(Math.abs(position.x - start.x) < 350 && Math.abs(position.y - start.y) < 350)
             return { currentSlide };
           }

           // TODO: Additional logic for swiping up & down?

           return { currentSlide: currentSlide + (position.x > start.x ? 1 : -1), start: null };

         } else if(type === "down") {
           return { currentSlide, start: position };
         }
      }, { currentSlide: 0, start: null });

      const touchDown = e => touch({ type: "down", position:  { x: e.clientX, y: e.clientY }});
      const touchUp = e => touch({ type: "up", position:  { x: e.clientX, y: e.clientY }});

      const slide = slides[currentSlide];
      //...
  });
```

Comment: Oh gosh, I just slapped my forehead when I read what you said about not needing to persist the `endX` :)), thank you! That was really refreshing, you made me question why I was thinking like that in the first place, using `e.screenX` directly solves the problem and is much more logical... I didn't understand though, what you meant by _There are just two events needed for your_ **reducer**: _touchdown and touchup. Everything else should be done inside the_ **reducer**. Nor did I understand what you meant by _split up the state into logical units (i.e. slide loading & swiping)_ but could you

Comment: **please** give me some example relating to the code I posted or some other sample code, it sounds very important and like a good lesson but, I'm not ashamed to admit its pretty hard for me to understand without practical examples :) I would very much appreciate it since I wanna learn and do things correctly!

Comment: @nick09 I'm currently afk, so I can't provide you with a  working & tested example. I hope the code as shown allows you to create one on your own though. If it somehow doesn't work, feel free to ping me, I'll look at it later then.

Comment: Sorry I didn't notice that you've already posted a sample code of the theory :) Thank you very much! I will fiddle around with it and see if I can make it work like that, thanks again!